# Values of $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ so that the function $g_\alpha(x)=x^\alpha \ln x$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

How to find out the values of $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ so that the function $g_\alpha(x)=x^\alpha \ln x$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,\infty)$?

Since for uniform continuity of $g_\alpha(x)$ on $(0,\infty)$, it is necessary that the existence of $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}g_\alpha(x)$, thus we must have $\alpha>0$, but how can we find out an upper bound for $\alpha$?

Also, since for $\alpha>0$, $g_\alpha(x)$ is continuous on $(0,a],~a>0$, we have $g_\alpha(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,a]$, how can we extend the uniformity towards right side?

Comment: Uniform continuity is very related to bounded derivative. That should give you an idea for what upper bound of $\alpha$ ought to be reasonable.

Comment: It will be uniformly continuous if the derivative is bounded and that happens if $\alpha<1$.